# How to know which component i am inspecting?

Tags: create-react-app, styled-components

I am using styledcomponents in my CRA. The thing is that when I inspect an element in the browser all I see is something like this:

```
<div class="js-cskdjf fdsfsjk fdsfds">..</div>
```

No idea what component this is , how can I figure this out? I have ejected the app too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CRA v2, then it supports [babel-plugin-macros](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros)

You can use the [babel macro](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro) from styled components by changing the main import to:

```
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components/macro';
```

This will bring in all properties of the babel plugin that styled components (which you will have to eject to add) This includes better debugging experience, by showing component names inside the devtools. More more information on this, [read docs here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging).

Answer (score -3):

You can use 'React Developer Tools' extension to see the Components layout:

- [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi),
- [for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/).

Comment: @bierhier There is a new tab should appear called `React` aside of `Elements` in the developer tools: https://duaw26jehqd4r.cloudfront.net/items/3A1u130I1x021I1G240z/Image%202018-10-27%20at%2011.37.56.png?v=938bd03a